# JS code generates error in Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to add following code in GTM to measure Web Core Vitals

```
<script type="text/javascript">
new PerformanceObserver((entryList) => {    
    for (const entry of entrytList.getEntries()) {
        const elm = entry.element;
        console.log(elm);
    }   
}).observe({type: 'largest-contentful-paint', buffered:true});
</script>
```

This code works in Console but when i try to publish it in GTM it generates error message as below

Not sure what is wrong with the code as it should support ECMA16 for GTM

[image]

Comment: The always helpful Simo Ahava has created a custom template for webvitals measurement in GTM (https://www.simoahava.com/custom-templates/core-web-vitals/) plus an accompanying article on web vitals tracking in GA4 (https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-core-web-vitals-in-ga4-with-google-tag-manager/), so maybe that is helpful as an alternative to your own custom script.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, GTM is pretty slow when it comes to ES6 adoption. It partially adopted it for things like templates, but not fully even there. And obviously it didn't adopt it for custom html tags.

What you'll have to do is rewrite your code to be ES5 compliant. Or you can use babel to do an automated transition. it will look like this:

```js
new PerformanceObserver(function (entryList) {
    var _iteratorNormalCompletion = true;
    var _didIteratorError = false;
    var _iteratorError = undefined;

    try {
        for (var _iterator = entrytList.getEntries()[Symbol.iterator](), _step; !(_iteratorNormalCompletion = (_step = _iterator.next()).done); _iteratorNormalCompletion = true) {
            var entry = _step.value;

            var elm = entry.element;
            console.log(elm);
        }
    } catch (err) {
        _didIteratorError = true;
        _iteratorError = err;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (!_iteratorNormalCompletion && _iterator.return) {
                _iterator.return();
            }
        } finally {
            if (_didIteratorError) {
                throw _iteratorError;
            }
        }
    }
}).observe({ type: 'largest-contentful-paint', buffered: true });
```

You probably don't need all the try catch and finally, but babel is being honest with what it does.

Comment: @Bnazruk, I had already converted code to ECS5 but it doesn't seem to work... that why i was wondering what could be wrong a piece of code is shared by Google Team in one of the videos..

Comment: They may have shared it for things like custom templates.

Comment: @BNazaruk this is probably not intended for use in GTM, since custom templates do not allow the "new" keyword.